# Exporting custom connect from Azure APIM based on a APIM product

Tags: azure-api-management, power-automate-custom-connector

I can successfully export a custom connector based on an APIM API.
I can successfully create a Product based multiple APIM APIs.

Question: Can I create a custom connector based on an APIM  Product?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the custom connectors to an APIM. Below are the steps on how to create custom connectors

- Navigate to your API Management service in the Azure portal.
- In the menu, under **APIs**, select **Power Platform**.
- Select **Create a connector**.
- In the **Create a connector** window, do the following:

```
1.  Select an API to publish to the Power Platform.
2.  Select a Power Platform environment to publish the API to.
3.  Enter a display name, which will be used as the name of the custom connector.
4.  Optionally, if the API is [protected by an OAuth 2.0 server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad), provide details including **Client ID**, **Client secret**, **Authorization URL**, **Token URL**, and **Refresh URL**.
```

- Then we need to click on create

[image]

- After creating open power apps to see your custom connector under DATA tab.
  [image]

Check [Custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/export-api-power-platform#create-a-custom-connector-to-an-api) for further details.